# HQL equivalent of SQL paged query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Can anybody help me to translate to HQL the following SQL query used for obtaining paged results?

```
SELECT *
FROM REPORDER repairorde0x_
INNER JOIN REPREPAIRDEVICE repairdevi1x_
ON repairorde0x_.ID=repairdevi1x_.REPORDERID
WHERE repairorde0x_.ID IN
    (SELECT id
    FROM
       (SELECT row_.id,
       rownum rownum_
       FROM
          (SELECT DISTINCT repairorde0_.ID
          FROM REPORDER repairorde0_
          INNER JOIN REPREPAIRDEVICE repairdevi1_
          ON repairorde0_.ID=repairdevi1_.REPORDERID
          ) row_
       WHERE rownum <= 550
       )
    WHERE rownum_ > 500
    ) ;
```

The part that i can't get to translate to HQL is the subselect where the IDs for the repair orders to be fetched are selected.
I don't know how in this case how to deal with rownum and several subsequent sub-select statements.

I need the HQL query in order to make the pagination on the DB level instead of doing it in memory in Java. (Query.setMaxResults, Query.setFirstResult problem for JOIN FETCH HQL queries warning : "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!")

Just to give a hint on the Java model of the entities:

```
class RepairOrder{
    private int id;
    private String orderNumber;
    private List<RepairDevice> repairDevices;
}

class RepairDevice{
    private int id;
    private int repairOrderId;
    private String deviceName;
}
```

Comment: You can't write HQL without knowing the class model.

Comment: You should reduce the question to the part you are struggling with (eg. the rownum in the subquery). The question might be closed as "too localized". There is a bigger chance to get an answer for short questions anyway. Not everyone has much time to read / understand long and complex questions.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I've modified the SQL statement and added informations about the Java entity object model. I think that the question is now more readable.

Comment: I guess that there is no solution for this situation because (due to eventual ordering when using the ROWNUM parameter, a select from a subquery can't be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easiest to just page the repair orders and load the devices with additional queries, using batch-size to avoid N+1:

```
orders = session
  .CreateQuery("from RepairOrder")
  .SetFirstResult(500)
  .SetMaxResult(50);
```

This xml mapping will load the devices for 50 order at once (making 1+N a 1+(N/50)).

```
<bag name="RepairDevices" batch-size="50" ...
```

Comment: For the simplicity of the example I've added only one JOIN, but there are actually 3 joined tables, so I guess the solution exposed above wouldn't actually fit in my case.

Comment: I think it still does. You can't (shouldn't) join all these 3 tables, because they all multiply the result. It is much better to get only the (paged) main object and load referenced objects (lazily) in batches.